# d3.js selector to get text element's text only

Tags: d3.js, svg

My `svg` have `text` element and `title`. I need to get the text of `text` element only, which is `Zombieland (9)`. But it is returning me `Zombieland (9)Zombieland (9)` which is `text` and `title` element's text.

Following is my selector.

```
d3.select(".horizontalLable").text();   // return "Zombieland (9)Zombieland (9)"

<text class="horizontalLable" text-anchor="end" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 10px; alignment-baseline: hanging; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(365,2)">Zombieland (9)<title>Zombieland (9)</title></text>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no CSS selection way to do this but you can remove the title, select the text and then add the title back in again to accomplish it.

```js
var text = d3.select(".horizontalLable");
var title = d3.select(".horizontalLable > title");
text.node().removeChild(title.node()); 
console.log(text.text());
text.node().append(title.node());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<text class="horizontalLable" text-anchor="end" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 10px; alignment-baseline: hanging; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(365,2)">Zombieland (9)<title>Zombieland (9)</title></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there a not include selector available?

Comment: That's what I said in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Robert, If you feel my answer is useful, please feel free to add it into yours.

Comment: @John there's nothing wrong with more than one approach. Keep your answer, may the best answer win.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is the text that you want and not a reusable selector to the node, it is possible to build on [Robert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568493/5609762) without modifying the DOM by copying the text node into a virtual one which you can then manipulate.

```js
var text = d3.select(".horizontalLable");
var copy = d3.select(text.node().cloneNode(true))
var title = copy.select("title");
copy.node().removeChild(title.node()); 
console.log(copy.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<text class="horizontalLable" text-anchor="end" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 10px; alignment-baseline: hanging; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(365,2)">Zombieland (9)<title>Zombieland (9)</title></text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would prefer a non-intrusive approach which does not manipulate the DOM just for the sake of extracting some text, which is already there. The `<text>` element has a property [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) which, in your case, holds two nodes of different [types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Constants): one of type `TEXT_NODE` containing the actual text content you are after, and the other of type `ELEMENT_NODE`, which is the `<title>`. Thus, you can easily sift through these nodes looking for just the one(s) you are interested in.

```js
var text = d3.select(".horizontalLable").node();
var textNodes = Array.from(text.childNodes)         
  .filter(c => c.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE);  
  
console.log(textNodes[0].textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <text class="horizontalLable" text-anchor="end" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 10px; alignment-baseline: hanging; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(365,2)">Zombieland (9)<title>Zombieland (9)</title></text>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, basically the same yet more D3-*ish*, you could do something like this:

```js
var text = d3.select(".horizontalLable")
  .selectAll(function() {
    return Array.from(this.childNodes)         
      .filter(c => c.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
  })
  .text();
  
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg>
  <text class="horizontalLable" text-anchor="end" alignment-baseline="hanging" style="font-size: 10px; alignment-baseline: hanging; font-family: Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(365,2)">Zombieland (9)<title>Zombieland (9)</title></text>
</svg>
```

---

**Side note:** Since fiddling with the DOM is quite an expensive operation when it comes to performance I decided to set up a [test case](https://jsperf.com/svg-text-without-children) to compare the solutions proposed by the answers to this question. As it turns out, my first approach is the fastest because it avoids manipulating the DOM while mostly using vanilla JS. The second solution, which utilizes D3, performs slower, if only by some 10 percent. In third place comes [Robert Longson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47568493/4235784) removal and subsequent appending of the `<title>`, which is 30-50 percent slower depending on the browser in use. The slowest implementation is [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47578185/4235784) cloning of the node performing roughly 70-80 percent slower.

Whatsoever, these results should not be overemphasised; it was just out of curiosity I did the test case and I wanted to share the results. For what it's worth, the main concern here should be ease of use, clarity, brevity and intelligibility of your code.